# Automapper doesn't ignore property for descendants

Tags: c#, automapper

First I'm using automapper 4.2.1. I have a class that represents tree view node. For example this class has three properties and one method:

```
class A
{
     public string Name{get; set;}
     public bool IsExpanded{get; set;}
     public ObservableCollection<A> Children {get; set;}

     public void UpdateCurrenNode(A object)
     {
        Mapper.Map(object, this);
     }
}
```

As you can see I have a method that helps me to update current node and its descendants with given object. But I want to ignore property IsExanded. So here is my Map:

```
CreateMap<A, A>().ForMember(dest => dest.IsExpanded, opts => opts.Ignore());
```

But after mapping property IsExpanded is ignored only for root object, but it doesn't ignored for descendants. Where am I wrong?

Thanks! Regards, Dmitry

Comment: you have specified to ignore mapping for  that property only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
CreateMap<A, A>().ForMember(dest => dest.IsExpanded, opts => opts.Ignore())
                 .ForMember(dest => dest.Children, 
                            opt => opt.MapFrom(src => 
                                               src.Children.Select(Mapper.Map<A, A>).ToList()));
```

For example:

Class A

```
public class A
{
    private static MapperConfiguration config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<A, A>().ForMember(dest => dest.IsExpanded, opts => opts.Ignore())
                             .ForMember(dest => dest.Children, 
                                        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Children.Select(Mapper.Map<A, A>).ToList()));
    });

    private static IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();

    public string Name{get; set;}
    public bool IsExpanded{get; set;}
    public ObservableCollection<A> Children {get; set;}

    public void UpdateCurrenNode(A obj)
    {
       mapper.Map(obj, this);
    }
}
```

Program

```
var test1 = new A()
{
    IsExpanded = true,
    Name = "Test1",
    Children = new ObservableCollection<A>()
};

var test2 = new A()
{
    IsExpanded = true,
    Name = "Test2",
    Children = new ObservableCollection<A>()
};

var test3 = new A()
{
    IsExpanded = true,
    Name = "Test3",
    Children = new ObservableCollection<A>()
};

var test = new A()
{
    IsExpanded = true,
    Name = "Test",
    Children = new ObservableCollection<A>() {test1, test2, test3}
};

var clone = new A()
{
    Children = new ObservableCollection<A>()
};

clone.UpdateCurrenNode(test);
```

Produces: 
[image]

---

### UPDATE

The above example, is also working fine with your original config:

```
cfg.CreateMap<A, A>().ForMember(dest => dest.IsExpanded, opts => opts.Ignore());
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: I have tested it, and it works on my side. How are you using the mapper?

Comment: I created profile and then initialized mapper with adding profile in Locator. I'm using MVVM Light toolkit

Comment: I have added an example, see if it helps

Comment: Well, it's a kind of magic. Seems I have to find a problem in a different place. Thanks!